# how to access the text in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

how do i get the text of the area which is marked by "***" is written(For JFileChooser)
   File Name: [***]
   Files of Type []
   i.e. i am asking for some built in "get" function if there is any and if not please tell        any other feasible way to access it;

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
*Desktop class only can get when you use JDK 6
*/
import java.awt.Desktop;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import java.io.File;

public class OpenFileUsingJFileChooser
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{

 JFileChooser fileChooser=new JFileChooser();


 int a=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);


 if(a==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
 {
  File fileToOpen=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

  try
  {
   Desktop.getDesktop().open(fileToOpen);
  }
  catch(Exception exception)
  {
   System.out.println("Problem occour when to open the file");
  }
 }
}
}
```

font:http://java2everyone.blogspot.com.br/2009/02/open-file-using-jfilechooser.html

Comment: no i am not asking the name of the selected file i am asking how do i get the text when the user is typing a file name such as in a "save as" option

Answer (score 0):

The "Save As" file is in fact the `File` returned from `getSelectedFile`. The `File` returned is based on the text in the dialog:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   File saveAsFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
   System.out.println(saveAsFile);
}
```